# Mongo - Aggregate Group Lookup Values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to sum up values that are listed within a lookup. I have 2 collections:

**Subscriptions**  (Pseudocode)

```
{
   _id,
   purchaseDate: Date,
   wholesalePrice: Number,
   purchasePrice: Number,
   retailPrice: Number,
   userID: String,
}
```

**Payments**

```
{
   _id,
   statementMonth: String, // e.g. 2020-08 (same as grouped id in Subscriptions)
   paymentDate: Date,
   userID: String,
   amountPaid
}
```

Users will need to transfer profit margin value at end of month. Therefore, I want to create an output for Statements. These will have all Subscriptions and Payments grouped into monthly records, with a summary of all the data within them. I have managed to create everything up to the first group, however once I do my lookup to get Payment details, everything seems to fail.

This is my current pipeline

```
    {
        "$match": {
            "userID": [provided UserID]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "format": "%Y-%m",
                    "date": "$purchaseDate"
                }
            },
            "totalWholesalePrice": {
                "$sum": "$wholesalePrice"
            },
            "totalPurchasePrice": {
                "$sum": "$purchasePrice"
            },
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1.0
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "totalAmountDue": {
                "$subtract": [
                    "$totalPurchasePrice",
                    "$totalWholesalePrice"
                ]
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "transactions",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "statementMonth",
            "as": "transactions"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$transactions",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$sort": {
            "_id": -1.0
        }
    }
```

This returns 2 records if 2 transactions:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "2020-08", 
    "totalWholesalePrice" : NumberInt(89), 
    "totalPurchasePrice" : 135.55, 
    "count" : 8.0, 
    "totalAmountDue" : 46.55, 
    "transactions" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f3faf2216d7a517bc51bfae"), 
        "date" : ISODate("2020-04-20T11:23:40.284+0000"), 
        "statementMonth" : "2020-08", 
        "merchant" : "M1268360", 
        "amountPaid" : "40"
    }   
}

{ 
    "_id" : "2020-08", 
    "totalWholesalePrice" : NumberInt(89), 
    "totalPurchasePrice" : 135.55, 
    "count" : 8.0, 
    "totalAmountDue" : 46.55, 
    "transactions" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f3fc13f16d7a517bc51c047"), 
        "date" : ISODate("2020-04-20T11:23:40.284+0000"), 
        "statementMonth" : "2020-08", 
        "merchant" : "M1268360", 
        "amountPaid" : "2"
    }
}
```

I would like final JSON to be:

```
    { 
        "_id" : "2020-08", 
        "totalWholesalePrice" : NumberInt(89), 
        "totalPurchasePrice" : 135.55, 
        "count" : 8.0, 
        "totalAmountDue" : 46.55, 
        "transactions" : [{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f3faf2216d7a517bc51bfae"), 
            "date" : ISODate("2020-04-20T11:23:40.284+0000"), 
            "statementMonth" : "2020-08", 
            "merchant" : "M1268360", 
            "amountPaid" : "40"
        } 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f3fc13f16d7a517bc51c047"), 
            "date" : ISODate("2020-04-20T11:23:40.284+0000"), 
            "statementMonth" : "2020-08", 
            "merchant" : "M1268360", 
            "amountPaid" : "2"
        }],
        "totalPaid" : 42, 
        "totalBalance" : 4.55, 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$id",
      "transactions": { //Grouping transactions together
        "$addToSet": "$transactions"
      },
      "totalWholesalePrice": {//As all values are unique getting the first
        "$first": "$totalWholesalePrice"
      }
      //Similarly add the needed fields - use $first, $addToSet
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E7YL-_I3Dg_)

To get the total:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$id",
      "transactions": {
        "$addToSet": "$transactions"
      },
      "totalWholesalePrice": {
        "$first": "$totalWholesalePrice"
      },
      "totalAmountPaid": {
        $sum: {
          $toInt: "$transactions.amountPaid" //you stored as string, convert to appropriate type
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XDCMmsJJVZ2)

Comment: Thanks Gibbs, that has helped grouping the transactions, however, how can I obtain a sum value of amountPaid?

I tried: totalPaid: { $sum: "$transactions.amountPaid" }. Should be 42 however I get 0

Comment: Gipps - you're a gun! Solved a problems I've been trying to get around all day. Thanks

Comment: accepted, unfortunately my rep is too low to upvote. hopefully this helps others and they upvote

Comment: No issues keep rocking :)